# Querying Multiple Fields in a Database

Tags: android, sqlite

For example, I have this table:

[image]

I am using the following method to query from that table:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getAllViandCategory() {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + "tbl_viand_category";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                data.add(cursor.getString(0));
                data.add(cursor.getString(1));
                data2.add(data);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }
        return data2;
    }
```

I am not getting the desired output. I am getting this: `[1,Fish,2,Vegetables,3,Meat,4,Rice,5,Etc]` instead of `[[1,Fish],[2,Vegetables],[3,Meat],[4,Rice],[5,Etc]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a List of Lists. The outer list has objects which has lists.

```
// Code to add a list object into outer list.
data2.add(data);
```

You will notice that you have created the data object just once. So basically the same object is inserted into data2 again and again.

You need to create a new data object for each iteration.

```
// New Code
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            data = new ArrayList<String>();
            data.add(cursor.getString(0));
            data.add(cursor.getString(1));
            data2.add(data);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
```

Hope that helps :D